# Product Title is not appearing on the single product page

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, themes, custom-wordpress-pages, elementor

i am using elementor page builder to design the single product page but for some reason the product title in not appearing on the page and while editing the page in the builder as well. i have tried clearing the cache and tried the css codes which i found in other forums but nothing is working. i checked the themes own customize section and when i change the html tag from H1 to H2 the title appears but in the page builder (elementor) its not working. i think the product should be and H1 tag instead of H2. If i deactivate one of it (the plugin or the theme) the title with h1 tag starts appearing. First i deactivated elementor, the product title start appearing on the default single product page then i switched the theme to another, the single product page that i created using elementor started appearing with h1 product title. I guess there is a conflict between the theme and the plugin
I will appreciate any solutions

The theme i am using is oceanwp

The page I need help with: http://dev.gemforia.com/product/opal-moon-ring/

Comment: I checked your page. h1 tag and title is actually there but in css it is set to `display: none;`. In order to make it visible again, you need to find and change the css code that sets it to `none` to `block`. Or you can force it by adding this css code to your theme's additional css section: `h1.product_title {display: block!important;}`

Comment: I used this code and it works with the theme but it's not working with the page builder, i guess i have to change the none to block. Do you have any idea where will it be?

Comment: On theme customizer when i changed it from h1 to h2 its worked but thats not the case with elementor template even h2 tag is not working here

Comment: can you check it again i have activated the elementor single product template

Comment: Your product page is not displaying properly now. Before it was OK and just the title was missing.

Comment: Check it again i have added them back Thanks!

Comment: Abdullah, please add this code to your theme's styles (additional css in customization) and it should fix the problem. `.elementor-page-title, h1.entry-title {display: block!important;}`

Comment: Your welcome Abdullah, I'd be glad if you can flag my comment as helpful.